# Why do I get "fatal: No url found for submodule path 'TestLibrary1' in .gitmodules" for a submodule that no longer exists?

Tags: git, github-actions, git-submodules, git-checkout

## Problem

When I try to checkout my repository using GitHub Actions I get the following error:

```
fatal: No url found for submodule path 'TestLibrary1' in .gitmodules
```

## What I Tried

I tried removing the submodule.

As far as I can tell it is completely gone (it is gone from the folder & from `.gitmodules`)

However, I keep getting the above error.

## Question

Why is this still happening when the submodule no longer exists?

Is there somewhere that it is holding onto a reference that I can check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the issue could be that the old submodule path remains cached based on [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/bitbucket-cloud-fix-error-fatal-no-url-found-for-submodule-path-in-gitmodules-1188400518.html).

check the status of the submodule

```
git submodule status
```

remove the cache using the old/path returns from the previous command

```
git rm --cached old/path
```

try to checkout again and see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: When I run the first command the submodule does not show up.
I tried the second command anyway, and it says `fatal: pathspec 'TestLibrary1' did not match any files`

Comment: Have you tried to update git submodules? try `git submodule update` and then  `git submodule update --init --recursive`. make sure you have removed the submodule entery from `.git/config`. also you can remove git cache with `git rm --cached path/to/submodule`, if so, you need to init submodules with `git submodule init ` and then update again.

Comment: Removing it from .git/config worked. Thank you very much! Not sure why I couldn't find that before.

Answer (score 1):

Note that starting Git 2.40 (Q1 2023), you will be able to display more information with the verbose mode:

```
git submodule -v status
```

And you can remove the submodule `TestLibrary1` from your local Git config with:

```
git config --unset-all submodule.TestLibrary1
```

This is safer than editing the `.git/config` by hand.